# How to fill a terminal input field using python

Tags: python, terminal, automation

Hello I want to know is it possible to fill a terminal input field using python for automation purpose and also submit the data or press the enter button after filling the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can run terminal command inside your python file. Don't need that complex automation. `os.system("terminal command here")`

```
import os
os.system('VER')
```

Output :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.192]
```